# Is it possible to send as from 2 different Exchange accounts in Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

Is it possible to configure Outlook 2007 to send email's from 2 different Exchange accounts much like you can in Outlook 2010?  I recall finding a document that outlined this process (ensuring Exchange mailboxes have proper permissions) but I can't seem to find it.

I've tried this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291626 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291626  but it's not working.

Client is running Exchange 2010 on Server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want the "From" field so you can select the account you want to send from (http://onlineitpro.com/?p=395)? Or you want to know how to add additional mailbox to the same account and then enable the "From" field? Edit: Seems like you want to know the rights that'll enable "Send As", using `Add-ADPermission` with the `ExtendedRights` `Send As` is what you're looking for (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676368(v=exchg.141).aspx).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head - that was exactly what I was missing.  I was missing the AD permission 'Send As'.  Thank you!